# How can I access a predefined array of Strings in my Android custom view java class?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

I have a custom view that uses a `TextView` and a `Spinner`. I am trying to build the new view in a way that allows me to set the `TextView` text, the `Spinner` `entries` and the `Spinner` `prompt` from the newly created object. See the code below for how it works.
When I add the `entries` parameter directly on the original spinner it works fine. However, when I add it in the custom view I only get `null` when I try to access the array from the `SettingItemSpinner` class. 
It is worth noting that I have no problems accessing the `text` parameter or the `prompt` parameter.
So what am I doing wrong? 
I have tried to access the `entries` attribute as an `int`, a `String` a `CharacterSequence[]` I've called `getText(int)` and `getTextArray(int)`.

Using logcat to check the results shows that element in the `TypedArray` is always null. 
How can I fix this?

My custom view, is defined in the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="@color/ws_blue"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Settings Item: "
        android:id="@+id/itemLabel"
        />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/si_spinner_value"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

I  use the custom view in another layout file for a fragment, the section concerned looks like this:

```
<com.mystuff.serviceapplication.SettingItemSpinner
    android:id="@+id/si_wlan_presets"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="WLAN Presets:"
    android:entries="@array/security_type_array"
    android:prompt="@string/security_type_prompt"
  />
```

Notice these three lines:

```
    android:text="WLAN Presets:"
    android:entries="@array/security_type_array"
    android:prompt="@string/security_type_prompt"
```

the `text` attribute belongs to the `TextView` element of my custom view, and the other two elements belong to the `Spinner` element of the custom view. I can access the `text` parameter and the `prompt` parameter without any problems.

My the relevant section of my  `SettingItemSpinner.class` looks like this:

```
private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    rootView = (SettingItemSpinner) inflater.inflate(R.layout.setting_item_spinner, this);
    tvItemLabel = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.itemLabel);
    spinner = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.si_spinner_value);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            Log.i("SPINNER: ", "You selected item: " + spinner.getSelectedItem());
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });

    int[] attrs = {android.R.attr.text, android.R.attr.entries, android.R.attr.prompt};
    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attributeSet, attrs);
    String text = a.getString(0);
    Log.i("SPINNER", "text string: " + text);
    String prompt = a.getString(2);
    Log.i("SPINNER", "prompt string: " + prompt);
/*
 *  I expect to get access to the security_type_array somewhere here where I
 *  will parse it into an array of Strings before continuing below
 */

    List<String> itemList = new ArrayList<String>();

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context.getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, itemList);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setPrompt(prompt);
    tvItemLabel.setText(text);

    a.recycle();
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13747400/works-android-custom-component-access-array-in-strings-xml-supplied-via-layo post probably help

Comment: thanks, I'll check it out.

Comment: Nope, that doesn't help, I still can't access the array from the `SettingItemSpinner` class. I keep getting `null`